# How to retrieve data from ckeditor 5 in angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor, angular7

I am using **CKEditor 5 in my angular 7 projects**. I have followed the official documentation and have retrieved the data whenever the editor content change using the **'ChangeEvent'**. Now I want to retrieve data whenever I click the save button.

1. I don't have the save button in **CKEditor's toolbar**, How to add it?
2. How to retrieve data whenever I click that save button?
3. I would like to use **CKEditor** in a form so that data is retrieved when the submit button is clicked. How to achieve this?

Here is the html code:

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor"  (change)="onChange($event)"  >
</ckeditor>
<button (click)=save()>Save</button>
```

Here is the TypeScript:

```
public Editor = ClassicEditor;

public onChange( { editor }: ChangeEvent ) {
const data = editor.getData();
console.log( data );
}

save(){
const data = this.Editor.getData();
console.log( data );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @Nagesh Katna

Comment: Able to retrieve the data but not get the image src. Why?

<p>Hii Binni<br><br>&nbsp;</p><figure class="image"><img></figure>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your save method you can't just call this.Editor.getData() since Editor isn't the instance 'editor' which has the data you want. In the onChange method you can assign the value to another component-level variable e.g. editorData: String and in your save method use that variable (e.g. this.editorData).

- S. Arora

btw, if anyway knows how to get a reference to 'editor' instance please share. Rather than getting the data onChange I was searching for a way to get it just once on save, when I came across this question.

UPDATE: I found a good way to avoid subscribing to onChange continuously by using ngModel 2 way binding as shown in the angular ckeditor demo here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/tree/master/src/app/demo-form

Answer (score 4):

I've found another way that can be used if you want to avoid using `ngModel`.

Put a name on editor in your template (in this example, I'll name it `myEditor`):

```html
<ckeditor #myEditor [editor]="editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

Then grab a reference of it in your component code (for some reason, I couldn't import the `CKEditorComponent` class, so I had to use the `any` type). With the reference it's possible to get the editor instance and from that instance - get the data. Here is an example (the `saveArticle()` method can be triggered for example from a button click):

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ArticleEditComponent {
  @ViewChild('myEditor') myEditor: any;

  saveArticle() {
    console.log(this.getArticleContent());
  }

  private getArticleContent() {
    if (this.myEditor && this.myEditor.editorInstance) {
      return this.myEditor.editorInstance.getData();
    }

    return '';
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `this.ckEditor` here?

Comment: @CJRamki that was just a typo. It was supposed to be `this.myEditor`. I've updated the answer

Comment: Able to retrieve the data but not get the image src. Why?

<p>Hii Binni<br><br>&nbsp;</p><figure class="image"><img></figure>

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <ckeditor id="editor"
  [editor]="editor"
  [config]="config"
  (ready)="onReady($event)"
  name="description"
  [(ngModel)]="model.description"
></ckeditor>
```

```js
 onReady(editor) {
      editor.ui.getEditableElement().parentElement.insertBefore(
          editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
          editor.ui.getEditableElement(),
      );
      this.newEditor = editor;
  }
  
  
  save(){
  
     console.log('this.newEditor data', this.newEditor.getData());
  
  }
```